# Allowing a host application to access a Java SDK installed in a Docker container

Tags: java, docker

I want to install an application that requires a Java SDK to be installed, but I don't want to install Java on my computer. Instead I would like to install Java to a Docker container and allow apps on my host machine to use it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible - you can put the JDK and the app into a container and run it. I'm sure you're aware you do have to have Docker installed, right?

Comment: I have Docker installed. I know how to create a Docker image with the SDK I need installed. I just don't know how to expose the SDK to my host machine.

Comment: You'll have to run the app from within the container as well.

Comment: Ok, the crux of my issue is I wanted an app on the host machine to use the JDK of a Docker container. I don't want to run it all in the container since my app has a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker doesn’t really work that way.  It’s best for packaged complete applications that you can access via a network connection; in the Java case, a JRE plus an app server plus an installed application would make a reasonable complete image.

It’s *possible* to share files between the host and a container, but mostly that direction is “push things into a container”.  In your example you could use the `docker run -v` option to push your source directory into the container, but you’d have to actually run the JDK commands (`javac`, `mvn`, ...) from inside the container.  You can use `docker exec` to do this, but it’s an unnatural workflow IMHO, and it requires you to have administrator-level privileges to do even routine things.

I’d put the JDK and the application in the same place: either bundle both into a single Docker image, or install the JDK on your host.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I thought,  but wanted someone with a bit more experience to back it up. The Docker learning curve is steep and I'm still working out what I can and can't achieve.